# JS Will not refresh with caching disabled

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser-cache

I have tried everything I can think of including appending .js files with ?ver=blah, and the browser still loads the old version of my script.

If I pull the script .js file up in the browser directly it is still the old file.

If I download it through FTP I get the new file.

I have tried both chrome and firefox browser(I installed FireFox fresh AFTER writing the new JS file, and somehow firefox is STILL loading the old file, which it had never even been exposed to...?)

I added this code at line 30 in the latest verson:

```
    if (lastRecipeBlockIndex == parent.children().size()) {
        //find tallest column and set parent div height to match
        var tallID = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < columnHeights.length; i++){
            if (columnHeights[i] > columnHeights[tallID])
                tallID = i;
        }
        parent.height(columnHeights[tallID]);
        return;
    }
```

Line 31 used to be a return statement.

Url to this file: http://tmurraywellness.com/wp-content/plugins/TM%20Code/TM-script.js?ver=0.01j

What does anyone else see?

The server has to be sending the wrong file. Caching is impossible since I have changed the url. Caching as mentioned is disabled anyway with dev-tools open in both browsers(I manually ticked the box to make that happen)

Any suggestions? I am desperate. I have spent hours trying to get the ten lines of code below to execute in my browser(s)

Comment: I see the code you posted.

Comment: There could be server side caching, also some services offer automatic "optimization" meaning they minify/precompress your files, which is not instant.

Comment: Currently line 30 is the `if (lastRecipeBlockIndex == parent.children().size()) {` statement when I download the script.  If you installed Firefox after the change and still got the old script then server must have been caching or serving a file from a different location than where you were making changes.